# XML communication between server and client using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Goodday,

I am currently having problems sending back a XML file to a server from a client. I am using the following javascript to send a request for a xml file on the server:

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     //this function would parse the contents of the xml to the webpage
            MyFunction(this); 
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "Home.xml", true);
 xhttp.send();
}
```

This works, i can succesfully parse the contents to variables I can then use in HTML. Now in order to save settings i made to the system that runs the server I want to send back the XML file with appended values. The server can then parse the contents of the appended XML file to flash so that next time the appended XML file is send to the client in case of a request.

I have found that I can use xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tag")[0].appendChild(node); to append nodes in the XML file but i fail to understand how I can then send back the file to the server.

Can i use xhttp.send() in a way that it not only sends a request but sends a XML file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I highly recommend you use a higher/level framework such as jQuery or Angular, it will save you a lot of time, getting or posting data with such libraries will need much less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out and thought I'd post the answer for people that are interested.

Quickly after I posted the question I came across the following article by Chris Minnick: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-send-receive-xml-data-from-the-server.cfm

His example made things a lot more clear on how to handle sending XML data via HTTP POST. Apparently, in the case of a POST request you can use XMLHttpRequest().send("your xml data") to send the data.

My javascript:

```
var xml_received = 0;

function loadXMLDoc() {
    // Create an XMLHttpRequest object to make a XML document request from server
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("GET", "home.xml", true);

    // This code listens for a change in the state of xhttp
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            // Request was succesfull so assign the response to the variable we created
            xml_received = processXML_index(this);
        }
    };
    // Set request header so the server reads the contents as xml
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); 
    // Send the request
    xhttp.send();
}

function sendXML_index() {
    // Create an XMLHttpRequest object to make a XML document request from server
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.open("POST", "", true);

    // This code listens for a change in the state of xhttp
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            // Request was succesfull
        }
    };

    // Set request header so the server reads the contents as xml
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); 
    xml_appended = appendXML(xml_received);
    // Send the request
    xhttp.send(xml_appended);
}

function processXML_index(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var txt = "";

    txt = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("palette")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

    return xmlDoc;
}

function appendXML(xml) {
    // currently doesn't append anything but just echoes the xml file
    return xml;
}
```

I wrote the function LoadXMLDoc() which loads a predefined XML file from the server with a GET request. When the request is succesfull the function processXML_index(this) will parse the data to the webpage and return the xml string which is then stored in xml_received.

When I press a button on the webpage the function SendXML_index() is called. This function calls the appendXML() function which takes the received XML data as an argument and returns an appended (new values entered via the webpage) xml file (as a string). This string is then send back to server using xhttp.send(xml_appended).

To append the data in the XML file you can use XMLHttpRequest().appendChild(). or xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("node")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "new content".

For examples of this, see: https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_examples.asp